# HtmlAgilityPack HasAttribute?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

All I want to do is

```
node.Attributes["class"].Value
```

But if the node doesn't have the `class` attribute, it crashes. So, I have to check for its existence first, right? How do I do that? `Attributes` is not a dict (its a list that contains an internal dict??), and there's no HasAttribute method (just a HasAttributes which indicates if it has any attribute at all). What do I do?

Comment: Are you sure checking for `node.Attributes["class"]` does not return null?

Comment: @Kirk: Right you are.... thought it threw an exception for some reason. Good call.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Use `node.Attributes["class"]?.Value` to return `null` if the attribute is missing. This will be the same as the `ValueOrDefault()` below.

**Original answer**

Try this:

```
String val;
if(node.Attributes["class"] != null)
{
  val = node.Attributes["class"].Value;
}
```

Or you might be able to add this

```
public static class HtmlAgilityExtender
{
    public static String ValueOrDefault(this HtmlAttribute attr)
    {
        return (attr != null) ? attr.Value : String.Empty;
    }
}
```

And then use

```
node.Attributes["class"].ValueOrDefault();
```

I havent tested that one, but it should work.

Comment: wish that they would implement something like
val = node.Attributes["class"].Value ??? "";  if you just don't care about nulls anywhere...

Comment: @Doggett, you can create an `IfNotNull` extension method that would allow `node.Attribute["class"].IfNotNull(x => x.Value)`.  Not exactly what you're looking for, but I use it all the time for this sort of problem.

Comment: @Kirk nice, never though of that, and just noticed you can make it completely generic so it works on any type.. Cool :) Still would love the ??? or something similar though ;)

Comment: There actually is a `GetAttributeValue` method already... no need to add another one.

Comment: That should do it: 
string classValue = node.Attributes["className"]?.Value;

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
String abc = String.Empty;     
      if (tag.Attributes.Contains(@"type"))
      {
          abc = tag.Attributes[@"type"].Value;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code Can Be Used to get all text between two script tags.

```
String getURL(){
return @"some site address";
}
List<string> Internalscripts()
    {
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlWeb().Load((@"" + getURL()));
        //Getting All the JavaScript in List
        HtmlNodeCollection javascripts = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script");
        List<string> scriptTags = new List<string>();
        foreach (HtmlNode script in javascripts)
        {
            if(!script.Attributes.Contains(@"src"))
            {
                scriptTags.Add(script.InnerHtml);
            }
        }
        return scriptTags;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Agility Pack has the capability to check if a node has a particular class or provide a list of all classes.

```
    //Select nodes example, get all <p> tag nodes and check if they have a class and if they do, get the class attribute.
foreach (HtmlNode node in htmlAgilityDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p"))
{
    if (node.HasClass("ClassName"))
    {
        HtmlAttribute classAttributes = node.Attributes["ClassName"];
        //Do something ...
    }
}

//Select nodes example, get all <p> tag nodes having a specified class name.
string className = "class";
foreach (HtmlNode node in htmlAgilityDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@class='" + className + "']"))
{
    //Access via class attribute
    HtmlAttribute classAttribute = node.Attributes[className];
    //Do something ...
}

//Get all class names to check for a class
bool containsClass = htmlAgilityDocument.DocumentNode.GetClasses().Contains("ClassName");
if (containsClass == true)
{
    //Do something ...
}
```