# Parse Html file using html agility pack c#

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

I want to find values of all type in an html code. I used html agility pack here is my code:

```
doc.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());
foreach (HtmlNode input in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input"))
{
     HtmlAttribute value = input.Attributes["value"];
     Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

the output of the code is just htmlagilitypack.htmlattribute. can you tell me what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Represents HTML tag attribute. If you need a value of it, you must use its `Value` property.

For example:

```
doc.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());
foreach (HtmlNode input in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input"))
{
     HtmlAttribute attr = input.Attributes["value"];
     if (attr != null)
        Console.WriteLine(attr.Value);
}
```

For HTML:

```
<input type=text name="myInput" value="Come get some!" />
```

output will be: `Come get some!`

EDIT: Null check added

Comment: im getting this error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.doc it is not empty because before i used this code it is return two times htmlagilitypack.htmlattribute and i have two line match this situation.

Comment: It occurs when input doesn't have this attribute. Check if attr is not null.
See question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090200/htmlagilitypack-hasattribute